# Using an alternate SMS sender, like Twilio for SFMC; what's the impact on Super Messages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms, sendsmsactivity

Quick question: we are evaluating using Twilio as our SMS provider with SFMC. We want to know if sending a SMS through Twilio will result in a super message charge.

So far, it appears that using Twilio would save us some $$ and provide better delivery reporting. If we can avoid needing to buy Super Messages for SMS, that's a major win.

We aren't getting a clear answer from our Salesforce Rep. We would appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you aren't going to get a straight answer from a rep, this directly cuts into Salesforce's finances.

Custom JB activities, such as Twilio's SMS Send aren't consuming any SuperMessages.

[**Here's**](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/assets/pdf/misc/super-messages-excluding-sms-mms-august17+.pdf) the most up to date list of different features of MC that are using them aside from MobileConnect's SMS/MMS.